# Wirecloud and IDM server hiccup

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

I linked wirecloud and Idm recently. When i login into wirecloud and i land into my wirecloud i got the following error:

```
Sorry, but the requested page is unavailable due to a server hiccup.
Our engineers have been notified, so check back later.
```

[image]

My idm configuration is:

```
URL
http://151.80.41.166:50002

Callback URL
http://151.80.41.166:50002/complete/fiware/
```

I cant get more error info

```
Exception Type:     AuthStateMissing
Exception Value:    Session value state missing.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py in validate_state, line 90
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.14
Python Path:    

['/opt/wirecloud_instance',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i got in the same machine idm and Wirecloud and they use the same cookie.

I add the follow lines on `settings.py`

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "wcsessionid"
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "wccsrftoken"
```